# Drafts in Apple Mail spinning out of control

Tags: macos, apple-mail

My draft mail continues to duplicate and keeps duplicating. It never stops. It is like the national debt sign that keeps adding and adding. I'm at 289.000 and counting.

What is going on here?

I have OS X 10.5.8. I closed Mail.app and the draft count went back to 837. One email sent has duplicated to some emails in Drafts – 25-50 duplications.

Comment: Which kinds of mail accounts do you have? POP? IMAP? (Check under *Preferences*)

Comment: Have you defined any [rules](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mail/3.0/en/9909.html)?